# Error when trying to search similar images using JSP

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jsp, numberformatexception

I am building a web application for feature extraction and comparing the feature of images, using JSP, Java, and PostgreSQL.

My feature extraction is extracting some features from images, so that then I can compare them (some features are about color, some on the histogram of the image and so. I have special methods that extract them using specific libraries (jars that I add into lib) as you can see in the following example!

Those features are then successfully being added into my PostgreSQL database.

```
public void GetImageProperties(String targetPath, ImageProperties imagesProperties) throws Exception
{
    // load image
    FileInputStream imageStream;
    imageStream = new FileInputStream(targetPath);
    BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(imageStream);        

    // get properties
    imagesProperties.cl = new ColorLayoutImpl(bimg);
    imagesProperties.eh = new EdgeHistogramImplementation(bimg);
    imagesProperties.sc = new ScalableColorImpl(bimg);
}
```

Then I add them into a postgresql database(only the features, not the images)

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE Images (" +
               "  imageid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY," +
               "  fname VARCHAR(128)," +
               "  colorlayout VARCHAR(512), " +
               "  edgehist VARCHAR(512), " +
               "  scalablecolor VARCHAR(512) " +
               ")";
```

I get this error every time I had loaded an image and want to compare it with all the other images in a directory.

```
HTTP Status 500 -     
type Exception report
```

**message:**

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

**exception:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /query.jsp at line 124

121:  if (bSearch) { 
122:    // get form params 
123:    query.setTopK(new Integer(request.getParameter("frm_topk"))); 
124:    query.setColorHistogramWeight(new Integer(request.getParameter("frm_weight_c1"))); 
125:    query.setColorDistributionWeight(new Integer(request.getParameter("frm_weight_c2"))); 
126:    query.setTextureWeight(new Integer(request.getParameter("frm_weight_c3"))); 
127:  }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)    
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)   
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)    
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

**root cause:**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)   
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)    java.lang.Integer.<init>
(Integer.java:677)  org.apache.jsp.query_jsp._jspService(query_jsp.java:256)    
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)  
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)    
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)     
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)    
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)   
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)    
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

Comment: Could you tell what is a feature extraction in detail?

Comment: I edited my question so that I describe the feature extraction process and I gave a little code about it so that you can understand what I am saying exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
query.setTopK(new Integer(request.getParameter("frm_topk")));
```

should be

```
String parFrm_topk = request.getParameter("frm_topk");
Integer frm_topk = null;
if (parFrm_topk != null && parFrm_topk.length() > 0 && !parFrm_topk.equals("null"))
try {
  frm_topk = Integer.valueOf(parFrm_topk);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
  throw nfe;
}
if (frm_topk ! = null) {
   query.setTopK(frm_topk);
```

this code is trying to check the parameter that could be empty, why it is empty depends on how flow the app and how parameters are passed through url.

Comment: It seems to be goin in a right direction.I suppose I should do the same on all 4 forms. I ve been programming all day.Do you see a error in the following code or is this the way its supposed to be done?(2nd textbox)

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /query.jsp at line 144

141:  Integer frm_weight_c1 = null;
142:  if (parFrm_weight_c1 != null && parFrm_weight_c1.length() > 0 && !parFrm_weight_c1.equals("null")) {
143:  try {
144:  frm_weight_c1 = Integer.valueOf(parFrm_weight_c1);
145:  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
146:  throw nfe;
147:  }

Comment: The error is not in the code but in the value of parFrm_weight_c1. The value should be a number. If you comment //throw nfe; then you may ignore the error but if the value is needed to work correctly you shouldn't do that. Instead you should find why this value is not a number.

Comment: Thank you Roman for your anwser, especially for catching the exception! GK!